# Why do I have wavy rainbow spots on my flicker free monitor?

Tags: hardware-failure

My old monitor has horizontal lines seen through camera, and my new monitor (Dell P2317H) has no horizontal lines, but I can still spot wavy rainbow spots using my phone camera at very close range, are they flickers? Is this intended? What are those called?

Comment: You will need to provide a picture, but I think this is simply how LCD screens work. Don't forget that a camera captures images in a rapid fashion, but not continuously (25 frames per second usually) and a screen does not emit constant light either, but updates every 60 frames per second too. As a result a camera will be able to see the updates which can give a distorted look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is probably a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).

It's not "intentional" but it's a natural effect, not a hardware failure. You should be able to minimise the effect by using the camera at certain distances - if you want to be close up, it may be unavoidable.

Comment: http://imgur.com/MIsbT4Z @Joe P

Comment: Yes, that would be Moiré patterns.